# Does Java (8 or11) provide a mechanism to update the java.security file?

Tags: java, security, pkcs#11

An app I am working on needs to have a security provider added to the java.security file in the JRE.

I am writing a script to make this change (along with others) but am wondering if there is a better way of doing this.  Currently, I am opening the java.security file, parsing non-comment looking for "java.security.#=", finding the highest number and inserting my new PKCS11 provider after that line.

The thing is, I can not guarantee the java.security file will be the same for all potential users and I'm worried my parsing script will miss some edge cases.  I am wondering if I could maybe run a Java method from PowerShell that adds the security provider programmatically or something. Because then the user could run that method before firing up the application, Is there a way to do that, or something similar?

Comment: If you develop your app correctly there is no need to edit `java.security` file (modifying this file should be only the last resort if everything else doe not work). You can instantiate any security provider at run-time and use it e.g. for crypto operations or limit ciphers suites. If you only want to publish an existing app you could build a package of application with included JRE (and patched java .security file). So you should better ask the question how to make your application work without modifying that file.

Comment: @Robert I am not "correctly developing" an application.  I am integrating a new feature into a black box system that I do not have access to the code base for, the only thing I have access to is the executable and supporting files distributed to our customers.  I have to work within those constraints which is why I asked the question I asked.  So you should answer the question I asked instead of telling me to ask better questions.  If the answer is "no" then just say that.

Comment: A lot of people are trying to do something because it was the first search result popping up at Google. For such cases it makes sense to provide alternative ways. If you want to publish a software to customers you should bundle the software with an own JRE that is only used by your software (where you can modify java.security as you need). Since Java 11 this is AFAIK the proposed way by Oracle (but I wouldn't use Oracle JRE as you have to pay for it, better use a different OpenJDK distribution like Eclipse Adoptium OpenJDK).

Comment: @Robert sorry for being snarky with you, I hadn't had my coffee yet and took my frustration out on you, providing alternatives makes sense, you are right.  

The software I am adding the pkcs#11 feature to has it's own JRE bundled with it.  The project actually uses a proprietary IBM version of Java which has been causing all of us headaches.  

My solution of modifying the bundled java.security file in the JRE works for what we need it to do, it is just not elegant. I worry about edge cases my script might miss but the only alternatives I can come up with require changes to the code base.

Comment: No problem. One other alternative would be to provide a complete custom java.security file and specify it as command-line option: https://dzone.com/articles/how-override-java-security